# A deck of 52 cards is revealed 1 at a time till an ace appears. Let $X$ be the number of cards revealed. Find the PMF and Expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

A deck of 52 cards is revealed 1 at a time till an ace appears. Let $X$ be the number of cards revealed until the ace. Find the PMF and Expectation(Can leave as a summation).

**Let me know if any of my thought process is wrong**

Since it's asking for a PMF it's going to be probabilities clumped up at different Xs(aka not a continuous function). The probability of drawing an Ace on the first draw is 4/52 then assuming you didn't draw it on the first draw it becomes 4/51 and this keeps going so I assume the PMF=P(X=k)=$\prod_{i=1}^k$(48-i/(52-i)) for $1\le k<48$. 0 otherwise.

With the PMF we know the expectation is going to be E[X]=P(X)*X. So that gives us $\sum^{47}_{k=1}k\prod_{i=1}^k(48-i/(52-i))$ because in worst can we'll have to draw 47 cards before we get an Ace and that's the case that the last 4 cards are aces.

Comment: How is a PMF not a function? It’s right there in the name. The domain of this function is discrete, of course.

Comment: sorry I meant a continuous function

Comment: P(X=2) is not 4/51, but 48/52*4/51. Can you see why, and generalise?

Comment: Right sorry I don't know the mathjax for it but I know exactly where you're going with it.

Comment: (If you want a product, it's just \prod, and it works the same as \sum). By the way, it is always a good idea to try to sum your PMF. We know it should always sum to 1, so you can test your answers that way.

Comment: Can you sum a prod by hand? Especially one that long?

Comment: @DylanY Probably not, but that is what CAS like Mathematica are for :)

Comment: If the index of your product starts at $\ i=1\ $, then the terms should be $\ \frac{49-i}{53-i}\ $, and the last term should be $\ \frac{4}{53-k}\ $, the probability that the last card is an ace.  That is, $\ P(X=k)=\frac{4}{53-k}\prod_\limits{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{49-i}{53-i}\ $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the answer is in a comment, I'll write it as an answer with some extra stuff.

So we want to find $P(X=k)$, for $1\le k \le 49$. Let's take $k=4$ as an example. We first need a non-ace card, which has probability $\frac{48}{52}$. Then another one, $\frac{47}{51}$, and another, $\frac{46}{50}$. Then we need an ace, $\frac{4}{49}$. So $P(X=4)=\frac{48}{52}\cdot\frac{47}{51}\cdot\frac{46}{50}\cdot\frac{4}{49}$. This generalises to:
$$
P(X=k)
= \frac{4}{53-k}\cdot\prod_{j=0}^{k-2}\frac{48-j}{52-j}
$$
(Note that if $k=1$, the product is the empty product, which is $1$).

You seem to have no problem writing up the expectation, so I won't go into that (it turns out to be $53/5=10.6$ by the way). Note however that the possible values for $k$ are $\{1,\ldots,49\}$, not $\{1,\ldots,47\}$.

Now for the extra bit. We can rewrite the probability as:
$$
P(X=k) = \frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{52-k}{51}\cdot\frac{51-k}{50}\cdot\frac{50-k}{49}
$$
This form actually gives another interpretation. We think about the positions of the aces in the deck. The $k$'th card needs to be an ace, which has probabailty $\frac{4}{52}$. The other three aces have to be placed after position $k$, which gives the rest of the fractions (e.g. there are 51 spots left for the second ace, $52-k$ of these being after position $k$).